# isomorphic equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, vector-space-isomorphism

W. Ross Ashby states in his book "An Introduction to Cybernetics" that the system:

$\ x' =  1/2(x^2+y^2) + x*y + y$

$\ y' =  1/2(x^2+y^2) + x*y + x$

is isomorphic to the system:

$\ u' =  -u$

$\ v' =  v + v^2$

under the transformation:

$\ u =  x - y$

$\ v =  x + y$

can someone explain this properly?

Comment: Do you mean $\frac12(x^2+y^2)$ or $\frac{1}{2(x^2+y^2)}$?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Just compute $u'=x'-y'$ and $v'=x'+y'$.